# MqttPahoMessageHandler and Re-connect Rate Management

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, mqtt

We've noticed a few applications that use Spring Integration with MQTT have seen a lot of re-connection attempts in short time intervals, causing issues with a broker we're using. I think part of the issue is *MqttPahoMessageHandler* does not seem to use any connection backoff algorithm. For inbound connections it looks like *MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter* uses a constant backoff (e.g. *recoveryInterval*) and I think newer versions (>= 1.1) of *Paho* have support for exponential backoff. With *MqttPahoMessageHandler*, it seems every message publish causes a new connection attempt, if not already connected.

In our environment we've seen the following scenario:

1. Our broker receives a lot of connects in a short time period, causing MQTT will messages to queue up.
2. The will queue eventually reaches peak capacity.
3. The MQTT connection will not succeed:

   1. TCP connection is setup
   2. MQTT CONNECT message with will is sent
   3. The broker attempts to queue the will message, which fails
   4. The broker terminates the TCP connection

When this happens and if we're trying to send a lot of outbound messages, we see a lot of connection attempts from *MqttPahoMessageHandler* + *Paho*.

Is there a reason why outbound connections (*MqttPahoMessageHandler*) do not use a backoff algorithm for re-connects, similar to what is used for inbound connections (*MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter*) or with *Paho*?

I'd like to modify this behavior, but first wanted to understand if this was an intentional design decision?

Comment: I would guess this question would be better put directly to the project (via their github page?) rather than here, as this is probably the correct venue to discuss the changes you are thinking about.

Comment: I'm posting here based on instructions here: https://spring.io/questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Spring Integration outbound endpoints will attempt to connect on demand.

You can add a [Circuit Breaker Advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) to prevent that. When a configurable number of failures are detected, the breaker is opened and subsequent attempts will fail fast. After some time, the breaker goes half-open, allowing an attempt to be made; if that fails, it's opened again.

Comment: I'll review that. Thanks.